# Finding the different elements of an int list

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, typechecking

I am still new to OCaml, and want to write a function to find the alphabet, or the different individual numbers of an int list and return them as a list.
I came up with the following:

```
let rec find_alpha (list: int list) (acc: int list) =
   match list with
   |[]       -> acc
   |hd       -> if List.mem hd acc then acc else hd::acc
   |hd::tl   -> if List.mem hd acc then find_alpha tl acc else find_alpha tl hd::acc
```

The compiler says:

```
|hd       -> if List.mem hd acc then acc else hd::acc
                            ^^^
Error: This expression has type int list but an expression was expected of type int list list
Type int is not compatible with type int list.
```

Even though the message is quite explicit I can not figure out why an expression of type int list list was expected.
I check whether the `hd` element is already in the `acc` list. If it is, I return the `acc` as my result, if it was not in the `acc` I append it and return it.

Why is `int list list` expected?

I forgot to say, the first case `[]` should not be reachable, but I still included it for I don't know what reason. I should cut it out shouldn't I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second line of the pattern matching, you use `hd` as the pattern. This pattern matches any value and calls it `hd`. This makes `hd` an `int list` in the line

```
|hd       -> if List.mem hd acc then acc else hd::acc
```

When the compiler typechecks the call to `List.mem`, it happens to analyze the first argument first. Since the compiler already knows that `hd` has the type `int list` at this point, it infers that the second argument must have the type `int list list`, due to the type of `List.mem` (which is `'a -> 'a list -> bool`, with `'a` instantiated to `int list` here). If the function `List.hd` took its arguments in the opposite order or the compiler typechecked function calls in the opposite order, the complaint would have been that `hd` had the type `int list` but was used with the type `int`.

I'm not sure what you meant with this line. A list either is empty, or has a head and a tail. (I don't know why you think that “the first case [] should not be reachable”; a list certainly can be empty.) The usual pattern matching on a list is

```
match list with
| []       -> …
| hd::tl   -> …
```

and in your case you don't need anything more complicated. You can take your existing cases for `[]` and `hd::tl`. There's just one more thing to correct: you need to put parentheses in the recursive call `find_alpha tl (hd::acc)`, because `find_alpha tl hd::acc` is parsed as `(find_alpha tl hd)::acc`.

```
let rec find_alpha (list: int list) (acc: int list) =
   match list with
   |[]       -> acc
   |hd::tl   -> if List.mem hd acc then find_alpha tl acc else find_alpha tl (hd::acc)
```

Since the only variation in the `hd::tl` case is in the second argument passed to the recursive call, I prefer not to repeat the recursive call. Furthermore the functions don't depend on the type of the arguments, so I would let them stay polymorphic.

```
let rec find_alpha list acc =
   match list with
   | [] -> acc
   | hd::tl -> find_alpha tl (if List.mem hd acc then acc else hd::acc)
```

The code is arguably more readable if you define an intermediate variable.

```
let rec find_alpha list acc =
   match list with
   | [] -> acc
   | hd::tl ->
     let acc' = if List.mem hd acc then acc else hd::acc in
     find_alpha tl acc'
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation and details. I phrased that part with "should not be reachable" badly, I meant if the functions were called with suitable parameters they are not reachable- which is not smart, I see that it is much smarter to use [] and hd::tl to catch all cases that way, and get rid of [hd].

Comment: This would be a classic case for `List.fold_left (fun acc x -> if List.mem x acc then acc else x::acc) [] list`. Even better would be using a set for acc instead of a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
| hd -> if List.mem hd acc then acc else hd::acc
```

This case means "match the whole list and name it `hd` in the following" compared to

```
| [hd] -> if List.mem hd acc then acc else hd::acc
```

which means "match a list with only one element and name it `hd`.

In particular, with

```
| hd -> if List.mem hd acc then acc else hd::acc
```

`List.mem hd acc` is checking if the list of int `hd` belongs to the list `acc`. This can only makes sense if `acc` is a list of list of int. However, you precised that `acc` was a list of int; yielding the compiler error that you saw.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, thank's so much! Should my third pattern match say |[hd::tl] aswell then? Or is that covered by definition because hd is always the first list element and concat + tail is the rest?